# limits of sequences of values of a function form a closed a set?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Suppose $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function. I want to define a set $Z$ to be the set of $z \in \mathbb{R}$ such that there exists a sequence $(x_i, y_i) \in \mathbb{Z}^2$ such that
$$
f(x_i, y_i) \to z. 
$$
I am wondering is it the case that $Z$ is a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: It could be the case that $Z = \mathbb R$  e.g. $f(x,y) = x+y$

Comment: I don't mean a proper subset, so this is fine

Comment: Then all limit point in Z will be in Z and Z is closed.

Comment: Could you possibly provide me some details please?

Comment: These are equivalent definitions:  
A subset $A$ of a space $X$ is closed if its complement $X\setminus A$ is an open subset of $X.$ A set is closed in $X$ if and only if it is equal to its closure in $X.$  A set is closed if and only if it contains all of its boundary points.  A set is closed if and only if it contains all of its limit points.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. $Z$ is the closure of $f(\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z)$.